# atof not converting in single linked list

Tags: c, stack, atof

The input file should specify a single algebraic expression in postfix order supporting positive and negative floating point values and the following operations: Addition (+), Subtraction (-), Multiplication (*), Division (/). All floating point value and operations should be whitespace delimited. I have to scan in this following line:

4 5 + 20 3 - * -4.0 +

I'm getting an error when trying to convert the string i used to scan the argument into a float using the atof function and putting it into the linked list element. I'm also using a stack structure. Here's my code:
ListElmt.h

```
#include "bool.h"



#ifndef LISTELMT_H
#define LISTELMT_H



typedef struct ListElmt_ {
   float num;
   struct ListElmt_ *next;
} ListElmt;


#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "bool.h"
#include "listelmt.h"
#include "list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



#define BUFSIZE 1000

int stack_push(List *list, int data){

    return list_ins_next(list, NULL, data);
}

int stack_pop(List *list, ListElmt *data){
    if(list->top->num == data->num){
        return list_rem_next(list, data);
    }
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   FILE *ifp;
    char fileInput[BUFSIZE];
   char *newStr;
   List *argument_list;
   ListElmt *stack_elmt;
   int i = 0;
  float a=0; float b = 0; int c = 0;

 if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
{
    /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
    printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
}
else 
{
    // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
    ifp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

    if (ifp == 0 ){

        printf("Could not open file\n");
    }

    else{
            argument_list = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));

           list_init(argument_list);
           stack_elmt = (ListElmt*)malloc(sizeof(ListElmt));



        while (fscanf(ifp, "%s", &newStr) != EOF){

             if(newStr != "+" || newStr != "-"|| newStr != "*"|| newStr!= "/" ){

                 stack_elmt->num = atof(newStr);

                 stack_elmt->next = NULL;

                 stack_push(argument_list, stack_elmt->num);
             }

             else{
                 if(newStr == "+"){
                     a = argument_list->top->num;
                     stack_pop(argument_list, argument_list->top);
                     b = argument_list->top->num;
                     stack_pop(argument_list, argument_list->top);
                     stack_elmt->num = a+b;
                     stack_elmt->next=NULL;

                     stack_push(argument_list, stack_elmt->num);
                 }
                 else if(newStr == "-"){
                     a = argument_list->top->num;
                     stack_pop(argument_list, argument_list->top);
                     b = argument_list->top->num;
                     stack_pop(argument_list, argument_list->top);
                     stack_elmt->num = a-b;
                     stack_elmt->next=NULL;

                     stack_push(argument_list, stack_elmt->num);
                 }
                 else if(newStr == "*"){
                     a = argument_list->top->num;
                     stack_pop(argument_list, argument_list->top);
                     b = argument_list->top->num;
                     stack_pop(argument_list, argument_list->top);
                     stack_elmt->num = a*b;
                     stack_elmt->next=NULL;

                     stack_push(argument_list, stack_elmt->num);
                 }
                 else if(newStr == "/"){
                     a = argument_list->top->num;
                     stack_pop(argument_list, argument_list->top);
                     b = argument_list->top->num;
                     stack_pop(argument_list, argument_list->top);
                     stack_elmt->num = a/b;
                     stack_elmt->next=NULL;

                     stack_push(argument_list, stack_elmt->num);
                 }
             }

             printf("%lf", argument_list->top->num);





        }
    }
 }//list_destroy(argument_list);
   getchar();
   //return 0;
     }
```

I'm using visual studio so it doesn't tell me theres an error or anything but instead just breaks and goes to some weird file with atof.

Comment: Did u allocate memory for `newStr`?

Answer (score 2):

- For string comparison, use `strcmp()` or `strncmp()`.

  `if(newStr != "+" || newStr != "-"|| newStr != "*"|| newStr!= "/")` won't compare the strings as expected.
- only pointer is declared.

  char *newStr;

  so memory should allocated dynamically or by static. i.e `char newStr[MAX_STR_LEN];` or `malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);` MAX_STR_LEN is the expected maximum string length.

Comment: It depends on the definition of 'valid'.  It is compilable; it doesn't do what is wanted, though.